# How to create relative xpath for the angular js element?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I need to create xpath for the check box.It is a angular js element.I tried to produce xpath with firebug.But it is giving html xpath and its not useful.I would like to know how to create relative xpath for the checkbox.

Firebugxpath:

```
html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/check-box/div/div[2]/a
```

Firebug xpath not useful to identify the element.I tried some relative xpath with contains methos (i.e `//class[contains(text(),'email')`]).But its not useful

Could you please help me create relative xpath in different ways for following code?

```
<check-box class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" text="By email" name="email" ng-model="vm.options.byEmail" tab-index="3" style="">
<div class="MMM-check-box" ng-class="customClass ? customClass : ''">
<div class="MMM-label ng-binding MMM-label--hidden" ng-class="!label ? 'MMM-label--hidden' : ''" style=""/>
<div class="MMM-check-box__field" ng-keydown="onFocus($event)" tabindex="3">
<a class="MMM-check-box__link" name="email" ng-click="change()" ng-class="toggle === true ? 'MMM-check-box__link--selected' : ''">
<div class="MMM-check-box__title ng-binding">By email</div>
<div class="MMM-check-box__textarea-container ng-hide" ng-show="withTextarea && toggle === true" style="">
</div>
</div>
</check-box>
```

My element comes under this tag:

```
<a class="MMM-check-box__link" name="email" ng-click="change()" ng-class="toggle === true ? 'MMM-check-box__link--selected' : ''">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` of the element should be considered one of the most reliable ways to locate elements:

```
//check-box[@name="email"]
```

Note that the "model" is also usually a good way to locate Angular elements:

```
//check-box[@ng-model="vm.options.byEmail"]
```

If you are using `protractor`, you can use the [`by.model` locator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model):

```
element(by.model("vm.options.byEmail"));
```

Comment: when i give this xpath it is not clicking check-box.It is identifying check-box with its name.Not clicking inside checkbox,it is clicking on "email" text

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan okay, but what if you find the `a` element instead: `//a[@name="email"]` and try clicking it?

Comment: For that particular element working fine.However I ahve once check box as follow.But here I am not able to apply same logic. `<svg id="Layer_1" class="MMM-toggle__icon" xml:space="preserve" style="enable-background:new 0 0 51.9 41.9;" viewBox="0 0 51.9 41.9" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; version="1.1"> <style type="text/css"> .st0{fill:none;stroke:#2F8E9F;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterli‌​mit:10;} </style> <path class="st0" d="M16.9,36.1l-1.6,1.7L16.9,36.1l1.6,1.7L16.9,36.1z M16.9,36.1L49,2.8L16.9,364. //svg[@id="Layer_1"]`